# How do you get individual items from a List Item

Tags: android

i am new to Android development but am trying to get one element of a string variable but can't seem to figure it out.

```
@Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView walksList, View v, int position, long id) 
  {
  String selected = walksList.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
}
```

`selected` is returning me :

```
{root=WalkOneRoot, caption=WalkOneCaption, title=WalkOneTitle}
```

What I am trying to do is isolate 'WalkOneRoot' for each list item into a variable.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the listview set up with textviews you can simple use the textview to get what you want in your onListItemClick.

```
TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.root);
String myString = tv.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

`ListView.getItemAtPosition(int position)` is returning an generic object of type `Object`.  Instead of calling `toString()` on  `selected` you should cast it as the type of object it really is and then extract the `WalkOneRoot` value from it that way.

What type of object is contained in your list view?

Comment: Hi, WalkOneRoot is just text from a db field and will be the name of a walk, I have used 'WalkOneRoot' for testing purposes. There are around 40 walks all listed in sqlite db.

Answer (score 0):

The item that you're retrieving is the `View` which is why toString() is simply returning whatever overridden toString method you have in your View class. You could, presumably, override toString to only return the variable you're interested in.